Why does Eclipse use an old JRE by default?
I installed Eclipse 2023-06 (4.28.0) and tried to make a new Java project using JavaSE-20. I don't actually know what I'm doing with this, I just figured I should be using the most recent versions of anything. It does not work, I believe because Eclipse installs JRE 17.0.7 by default. I can get everything working using JRE 17, but my question is why Eclipse offers JavaSE-20 (and 18 and 19, for that matter) when the default JRE installation is 17. My limited experience as a developer has made me keen on always installing the most recent versions of everything so it seems a little strange to me that Eclipse installs a JRE that is (ostensibly) 3 full versions behind the most recent.
I browsed StackOverflow for a long time trying different solutions before realizing that 17 was the only JRE actually installed on my computer. I did not attempt to manually install JavaSE-20.

maybe you must ask the developers or designers of Eclipse. By the way, "3 full versions behind the most recent." - that would be Java 19 (23 is already at the Release Candidate phase :- )

Note that 17 is the current LTS-release.

@piet  Have I travelled back in time?!? OP stating most recent is Java 20, you that current LTS is 17 - I thought I've seen Java 21 as LTS  and I am using Java 22 (even 23 as RC)

@user85421 Yeah, you are right. 17 was the current LTS-version at the time of the eclipse-release (June 2023).

sure, that makes sense (Eclipse developers were not able to travel to the future :- )

@piet.t I think this is the answer I was looking for. Where do you see which LTS' are supported by which versions of Eclipse though? I couldn't find this info and honestly just didn't believe that there have been 5 new SEs--a 33% increase--in the past year.

You can tell Eclipse about other versions of Java installed on your machine in "Installed JREs" in preferences. You can then choose to use that Java for your project. Eclipse 2024-09 released this week supports all version of Java up to Java 22.

@user85421 I think this confusion is central to my question. You have 23 as the most recent version. Then Eclipse 2023-06 telling you that 20 exists, but even though it does, it only installs 17. If this version of Eclipse knows that JavaSE-18, 19, and 20 all exist, why does it install 17 by default?

It installs Java 17 because that is the Java that Eclipse itself needs to run and which it has been tested on. You can use other versions of Java for your code.

"I should be using the most recent versions of anything." -- then why Eclipse 2023-06 and not 2024-06  (I believe/hope 2024-09 is soon out)  || still that feeling of having travelled back in time, or is it just me living in the future :- )

@user85421 2024-09 should be released on Wednesday (11th) according to the project plan.

"why does it install 17 by default?" -- my guess, as already mentioned in comments above, it was the LTS version at the time it was developed/released -- but I never had Eclipse install any Java/JRE/JDK, but maybe because I always manually installed Java and only downloaded the naked Eclipse (some 15 or more years ago, only the relevant features)

@user85421 2023-06 is the newest version available in the school district as what apps are able to be installed on district-owned devices are determined higher up the ladder.

@MrHEdison Are you aware that this is a pretty bad idea for safety reasons? And if so, what exactly is stopping you from explaining it to those higher up the ladder? Please ask and report issues only on current versions. An outdated version is the newspaper of yesterday.

Java 20 became obsolete with the release of Java 21 in September 2023, as no vendor provided (security) updates from that time onwards. All Java vendors (there are a couple of more vendors than Oracle) provide(d) long time support (LTS) for Java 8, 11, 17 and 21. The next LTS version will be probably 25 (assuming other vendors will do the same as Oracle; depending on the vendor it can differ when the support ends and when you have to pay for it).

@howlger what exactly is stopping you? ignorance and a swamp of red tape. What are the safety reasons you are talking about? And are they realistic and severe enough that I could convince a bunch of people that know nothing about any of this that it's worth their time and energy to force an update on hundreds of district devices, and that they should do so any time a new version is released? As for posting about current versions, the core question I was asking is the same on 2024 Eclipse--why does Eclipse know about a higher version of Java than it comes installed with?

@MrHEdison What are the safety reasons you are talking about? - Attacks on the supply chain are on the rise. The IDE is also part of the supply chain; think of what harm a plugin containing malware can do, for example. Vulnerabilities are made public after a certain time so that they can be fixed before the bad guys can exploit them. Not updating means that the bad guys can simply use the known vulnerabilities.

@MrHEdison Why do Eclipse and other Java applications use LTS versions instead of a higher available Java version? - Since Java 9, there is no guarantee that a Java application will run on a higher version of a Java VM without modification. In contrast, when using an LTS version, you will get security updates for several years with the guarantee that you will not have to adapt your code.

Eclipse is itself a java app.
Like any java app it needs a JVM to run itself on. And like any java app, it is written 'targeted' at a specific JVM release, which means it will not run on anything older than the targeted release, and it should, but might not necessarily run on anything newer.
So, keep this in mind:

You have one JDK that you run on eclipse on.
You have, completely unrelated, a JDK that you compile the app against, and run your compiled app on; an app you developed in eclipse1, and
There is absolutely no reason whatsoever that those 2 should be the same JDK. In fact, it is a really bad idea to do that!

Separately:
JRE? That does not exist and hasn't since java 8. The concept is dead. The JRE concept is that the end user of the machine contracts with Oracle or some other vendor to install and maintain a JRE, and then the end user separately contracts with some vendor of an app, where the app-vendor takes no responsibility or effort whatsoever to ensure a JRE is available: That's oracle/enduser's job. That is dead and has always been dead; it's official since java9 - i.e. over 10 years at this point. In other words, as per the preferred way to distribute java apps, Eclipse must itself install a JDK version that it has tested itself against, and maintain it, so it is not at all weird that [A] eclipse's installer installs a JDK and [B] that it is version 17.
So what should you do
Take the JDK that eclipse installed and leave it alone. It's there for the benefit of eclipse itself.
Install the JDK you want yourself. Then tell eclipse about that JDK, and that you want that to be the default. Sure, go with JDK23. Why not? Then.. go forth, and program awesome things!

[1] Eclipse has no problem dealing with you having loads of JDKs installed; each eclipse project can be configured to compile against and run on a different one if for some reason you want that. This isn't crazy, either. You can have an app that is designed to run on JDK11 still, and one that is designed for JDK23, developed in tandem, why not? Eclipse will let you do that.

Thorough and well-worded--thank you! So 1.7 is the JRE that Eclipse 2023-06 itself was developed/tested against. And I'm guessing that SE-20 is an option because, at the time of release, it was the most recent available (in June 2023). But if the concept of JRE is dead, why do recent versions of Eclipse still use the term all over the place? If you make a new Java project, it appears at least 5 times in the resulting dialogue. Seems misleading to me.

Stop saying JRE, they don't exist anymore. Eclipse installed a JDK17 (not 1.7!). SE-20 is an option because, while Eclipse is designed to run in JDK17, it knows JDK21 is also a thing. Just, blindly upgrading to the latest is problematic, and forces all users of eclipse to update their eclipse-executing-JDK as well as their eclipse install. There is no benefit at all in doing that, so, eclipse doesn't.

Note that for Eclipse 2024-09 Java 22 is the latest that will appear in things like the complance list, a patch will be needed to fully support Java 23.

I understand JREs don't exist anymore. I am trying to point out that Eclipse itself still makes numerous references to the term. So if they are indeed obsolete then I I'm wondering why Eclipse repeatedly suggests otherwise.

I would assume someday eclipse will 'switch' to JDK21 (as it is an LTS release). This will require all plugin maintainers to test their stuff works on it (despite OpenJDK's claims, java is not guaranteed compatible like that. Also, Hyrum's law exists and cannot be worked around other than with actually testing). So that won't happen anytime soon, but, eventually, it will.

@MrHEdison ah, yes, now you are getting to entirely valid complaints. I don't know why eclipse continues to use the term 'JRE' e.g. in its preferences dialog when that term is dead and has been for a decade at this point. They should fix that.

Some JDK vendors continue to release JRE editions of their products. For example: Adoptium, Azul Systems, and BellSoft.

@MrHEdison they (probably) did not remove the JRE term from Eclipse since it still allows projects using older Java versions (BTW Oracle still uses the term JRE as part of the JDK, e.g in Contents of the JDK)

Why does everyone saying JREs don't exist anymore?  They do if you look around - https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?package=jre  And the idea that the app vendor is responsible for including a JDK in their installer goes completely against the whole "write once run anywhere" concept.  Maybe someone wants to run my app on some obscure minicomputer I've never heard of, if they can get a legit JDK for it, they can.  I'm not going to make separte install packages of my app for every type of computer out there, avoiding that is the whole reason to use Java!

@nigelg Because the concept has died. Oracle itself no longer releases them and JRE isn't just an application you can download and install, it is a distribution model. And that is gone. The JRE model is: "Given nigel (maker of app), jane (user of app) and Adoptium (provider of JRE): Jane and Adoptium arrange for jane's system to have a JRE present. Nigel isn't part of this equation and has no say or influence on this; it just is there for Nigel to use. Nigel's app runs on that JRE. The installation process just fails / the app does not run if Jane has no JRE". That? Gone.

@nigelg You can claim all day long that 'it would suck if it is gone' but that's not a logical argument. The java ecosystem never worked that way; not on computers. Every serious java-based on-device app shipped its own JRE, because [A] many systems did not have one installed so unless you wanted to turn off untold numbers of customers, you had to ship an installer anyway, and [B] by doing it yourself can control the exact version of it. The death of JREs as a model officially happened with the release of JDK9; but that was merely making de jure what was already de facto.

Your claim that this goes against WORA is hyperbolic. You still write once and it runs anywhere. Anywhere where the sysadmin, which is also you (this is the case when writing web backends in java, which, to be clear, is 100x+ more popular than frontend desktop apps in java) has run apt install openjdk-23-jdk or whatever. Or for frontend desktop apps: The app is WORA, the install script isn't. That's indeed quite annoying, but it is what it is.

Eclipse doesn't inherently use an old JRE by default. The choice of JRE typically depends on several factors:

Eclipse Release: Older versions of Eclipse might have been designed to work optimally with specific JRE versions. However, newer releases generally support a wider range of JREs.
System JRE: When you install Eclipse, it often tries to detect the JRE installed on your system and sets that as the default. If your system has an older JRE, Eclipse might use it unless you explicitly change it.
User Preferences: You can manually configure Eclipse to use a different JRE in the preferences settings.


-This is 2023-06, which is a little more than a year old. Is there documentation somewhere for which versions of Eclipse work optimally with which JRE? I don't see it here: link
-This is a brand new Macbook Pro, so there shouldn't be any previous JREs on here.
-I don't see a "Preferences" sub menu at the top bar (with file, edit, etc), nor is there one on the "Eclipse" drop-down. Any clue how to get to where you're talking about? And then I'd still need to install 20 manually, right?

In this specific scenario, I think the best way to solve the issue is to set up the default JRE in the Eclipse preferences.  So in this way Eclipse automatically use it in future projects.

@MrHEdison On macOS Preferences is replaced by the standard Settings in the Eclipse application menu.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation/ had that Eclipse and Java version recorded, but the Wiki server itself is no longer maintained. 2024-06 and later require Java 21, as it now exists as the LTS version. 2023-06 required Java 17.
